# Video from web cam is not streaming in iPhone/Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying this code but it shows a still image, and not proper video streaming. However it shows the video, but only for some time.

```
[reykjavikurtjorn loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://213.167.154.114/mila/_definst_/tjornin.stream/playlist.m3u8"]]];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.domain.com/myVideo.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                   object:nil];    

mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
```

and the delegate

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:player];

if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
[player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```